# How to keep the button focused on click of the button with alpine js?

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I deployed a simple survey form with laravel 8. When the user clicks on the rating button, the button color changes but the problem is when the user clicks it should focus on only the clicked button.  I need the clicked button color to be changed and stay focused on it even the user clicks outside.
How can I achieve this with alpine js?

The below code is the blade file. I am looping to show the questions and the rating buttons from an array from the controller page.

```
<div>
            @foreach ($formDetail as $num => $row)

            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 mt-2 p-4" wire:model.defer="formDetail.{{$num}}.question">{{$formDetail[$num]['question']}}</div>

            <div class="flex flex-nowrap gap-2 p-6">

            @foreach ($ratings as $index => $r)
            <div   x-data="{click:false}">
            <button type="button"   @click="click=true" :class="click?'bg-red-400':'bg-green-500'"      wire:click.prevent="chooseRate({{$index}},{{$num}})" class="rounded  text-white px-2.5 cursor-pointer" id="rate">{{$r}}</button>

        </div>

            @endforeach
            @error('rating') <div class="text-red-400"> {{ $message }} </div>  @enderror



        </div>
        <div class="p-8 flex flex-nowrap gap-6 -my-6">
            <span class="-mx-2">Lowest</span>
            <span class="mx-64">Highest</span>
          </div>

          <div class="flex flex-nowrap w-2/3 p-6">
            <textarea  wire:model.defer="formDetail.{{$num}}.comment" class="border-blue-200 border-2 w-3/4 h-16  focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none" name="comment" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alpine component:

```
<div class="flex w-full h-screen justify-center items-center">
  <div x-data="
    {
        rating: 0,
        hoverRating: 0,
        ratings: [{'amount': 3, 'label':'Okay'}, {'amount': 4, 'label':'Good'}, {'amount': 5, 'label':'Great'}],
        rate(amount) {
            if (this.rating == amount) {
                this.rating = 0;
            }
            else this.rating = amount;
        }
    }
    ">
    <div class="flex space-x-3">
      <template x-for="(value, index) in ratings" :key="index">
        <button 
            @click="rate(value.amount)" 
            @mouseover="hoverRating = value.amount" 
            @mouseleave="hoverRating = rating" 
            aria-hidden="true" 
            class="bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline p-1 w-12 m-0 cursor-pointer" 
            :class="{
                'text-gray-600': hoverRating == value.amount,
                'text-red-400': rating == value.amount
            }
        ">
          <span x-text="index" />
        </button>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Click here for live example](https://codepen.io/artjom-zabelin/pen/KKqXEbr?editors=1000).

Integrate with livewire using @entangle:

```
rating: @entangle('rateProperty')
```

Instead of using blade loop to show the buttons, provide the ratings as Json to the alpine component, like so:

```
ratings: {{ json_encode($ratings) }}
```

To read more about entangle see https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to alpine, when the user clicks on the button and and the corresponding value will be taken is done with laravel in the backend. Here I just want to highlight the clicked button with a color change and it should not loose the highlight when the user clicks somewhere else. so can u provide only those part?

Comment: Nice answer. I often find it difficult to know when to use Livewire vs. Alpine in doing some of the same tasks. I've discovered that things go smoother if I can try to favor livewire over alpine for the same thing. This is a nice way to explain that.